# how to define css to get the simple tabbed menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

[image]

can I have css for the above tabbed menu, I have tried many but failed to get exact design.
below is my directive, html and css code
my html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

my directive

```
app.directive('basictabs', function() {
    return {

      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
     templateUrl :'app/partials/basictabs.html',
         link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
             var jqueryElm = $(elm[0]);
             $(jqueryElm).tabs();
         }

  };
});
```

my css

```
#tabs {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Provide your tried code to help you

Comment: You can do it using bootstrap. check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs)

Comment: @user3824049 Take a look at my answer

Comment: What's the problem anyway, styles or behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using **[Angular-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)** easily, without going for using Jquery plugin.

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6K1REBrPxScN45PSu64b?p=preview)**</kbd>

**basictabs.html**

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Tab 1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab 2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab 3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

But if you are very specific and want to achieve that by using JQuery UI Try this out

**<kbd>[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5NNEYKPedyCrFf80pPM?p=preview)</kbd>**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

 </head>
 <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <basictabs></basictabs>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this could help you.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fKbBI)

JQUERY

```
$('#tabs a').click(function(){

  var tabId = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#tabs li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  $('.content > div').hide();
  $(tabId).show()
})
```